# Firefox-SDK contentScript returns null

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am currently writing a Firefox-Addon that automatically prints every new file from my schools website. All the files on the website are in a table and every row (where each file is) has the class "s2d". This is what i have so far:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var uploads;

pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
  contentURL: "http://uchronski.de/lernmaterialien/beruflicheschulformen/11fosinformationssystemeundnetzwerktechnik/index.php",
  contentScript: ['var uploads = document.getElementsByClassName("s2d");', 'self.port.emit("pageEntriesLenght", uploads.lenght);']
});

pageWorker.port.on("pageEntriesLenght", function(files) {
  uploads = files;
});
```

Here i'm trying to get the current amount of files hosted on the website but "files" is alway null. I have tried it with a pageMod, which worked, but I need to do it with a page worker instead and I have no idea what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You made a spelling mistake in the word 'length' in the contentScript. Try this:

```
  contentScript: ['var uploads = document.getElementsByClassName("s2d");', 'self.port.emit("pageEntriesLenght", uploads.length);']
```